# What input should I give to crc16 Method

Tags: c, embedded, crc16

This my Mod bus crc_16 embedded code. I have run this code in code block many Times. There is no error but I am not getting actual crc value. I should get crc 05C8 and I am getting 8512 right now.

I think I giving wrong input while calling CRC method. I am passing string and its length. So please help me.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define POLY 0x8005
    unsigned int ModRTU_CRC(unsigned char * mod_data,unsigned int length)
    {
    unsigned int CRC16 = 0xFFFF;

    unsigned int pos=0,i=0;

    for(pos=0;pos<length;pos++)
    {
    CRC16 ^= (unsigned int) mod_data[pos];

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if((CRC16 & 0x0001)!=0)
        {
            CRC16 >>=1;
            CRC16^=0xA001;
        }
        else
        {
            CRC16 >>=1;
        }
    }

    }

   return CRC16;

    }

   int main()
   {

    //char *frame = "010600081388";
   //  char *frame = "010300080001";

   char frame[7];
        frame[0]=0x01;
       frame[1]=0x03;
       frame[2]=0x00;
       frame[3]=0x08;
       frame[4]=0x00;
       frame[5]=0x01;
       frame[6]='\0';


     printf("%x\n",frame);
     int len = strlen(frame);
     unsigned int  crcv = ModRTU_CRC(frame,len);
    printf("%x\n",crcv);
   return 0;
       }
```

Comment: `frame[6]='\0'`: ouch: buffer overrun! your buffer is too short. may be overwritten just when calling `strlen` and get a different length as a result...

Comment: How many elements are there in your array `frame`? What is the last valid index of that array? Note that you don't *need* to terminate it since it's not really a string, but an array of arbitrary binary data. Use `sizeof frame` to get the size of the array.

Comment: Also, none of the "characters" in the array are printable, so printing it will not work. Furthermore, if you want to print the `crcv` variable as hex then use the `"%x"` format.

Comment: err, the value is hex, whereas you're printing decimal...

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre even i if i remove that or increase array size i am geting wrong crc value

Comment: @Shrikant agreed. But fix it anyway. it's wrong. Are you sure you're using the proper algorithm? the proper init value (-1 vs 0) ? finding the proper CRC is always difficult.

Comment: Lastly I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: You don't pass a string to this function, you pass raw bytes and number of them in the buffer. As for your test - doing `frame[i]=0x00;` is equivalent to `frame[i]='\0';`. Also, `frame[6]='\0';` does a write outside specified buffer. Also, test data "010300080001" if treated as bytes (0x01, 0x03 etc.) results in Modbus CRC equal to 0xC805. If treated as ASCII it's 0x49D2. Neither of those values is 0x05C8, nor 0x8512.

Comment: @ Jacek Ślimok ok ,then i should convert my string to bytes first and then pass to method?

Comment: You should indent your code properly

Comment: @Shrikant I don't know what you mean by "should" or "should not". This function accepts a buffer and its length and calculates CRC of it, in binary form. If you calculate CRC of something you read (data transmission received, file read etc.) then you take the data as-is without any additional conversions. Put it to the buffer, pass it to the function. However, if all you have is `010300080001;` then it is quite unclear how the data should be treated - as binary or as string. I would assume as binary, given the contents but again, it is just an assumption.

Comment: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: You aren't using the CRC16-IBM polynomial 0x8005 anywhere in your code, which makes it fishy. Sure 0xA001 is 0x8005 inverted but then why `#define` the polynomial? If I remember correctly, I believe that this algorithm should also invert the data buffer after the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is that in your original code you used `frame[2]=0x00;` followed by `strlen()`, which will interpret this as the null terminator and give the wrong size 2 instead of 6. You cannot use `strlen()` on binary data.

In the "fixed" version you hard-code the size to 6 so the bug was removed by accident. It has nothing to do with `uint8_t` versus `char` (although it is always better to use `uint8_t` for binary data).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define POLY 0x8005
unsigned int ModRTU_CRC(unsigned char * mod_data,unsigned int length)
{
unsigned int CRC16 = 0xFFFF;

unsigned int pos=0,i=0;

for(pos=0;pos<length;pos++)
{
    CRC16 ^= (unsigned int) mod_data[pos];

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if((CRC16 & 0x0001)!=0)
        {
            CRC16 >>=1;
            CRC16^=0xA001;
        }
        else
        {
            CRC16 >>=1;
        }
    }

  }

  return CRC16;

 }

 int main()
 {



        uint8_t message[80] = { // 6-byte test vector
  0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01
};
int message_length = 6;
 printf("%x\n",message);
// int len = strlen(message);
 uint16_t the_CRC = ModRTU_CRC(message,message_length);
 printf("%x\n",the_CRC);
        return 0;
   }


 `
```

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer? Is it a solution? What's different from the question? If you wish to add details to the question please edit it.

Comment: @ Lundin yes this is correct answer. I have change data type from `char` to `uint8_t ` .

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter the slightest, as long as you don't use numbers larger than 0x7F.

Comment: Now I just spotted the actual bug. I'll post an answer. Had you put the code through a debugger you would have found this bug after approximately 1 minute.